# Creating random alingment for a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, alignment

How can I create an array with number from 1 to 10 for example without repeating. Because I will use it to re-aling a matrix's rows.
For example of 1 to 10, I want my output as:
4 1 3 8 2 5 6 7 9 10
But I don't want to have repated numbers.
How can I do that?

Comment: Berk, you should give credit to Inquest if their answer worked for you (mark their answer as accepted). ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is -

`randperm(10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use
A = magic(4);
B = A(A<=10);
B will give you required matrix.